# I am trying to activate a event if a variable equals 0-100 how should i do that?

Tags: if-statement, lua, roblox

```
local part = script.Parent
local encounter

function wait(second)
    local ostime_vrbl = os.time() + second
    print( "timing of Lua wait function: ", ostime_vrbl );
end

local function onPartTouched(otherPart)
    local partParent = otherPart.Parent
    
    
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        encounter = (math.random(1,1000))
        --expand on random number generator later ;)
        print("value of encounter", encounter)
        
    end
end
part.Touched:Connect(onPartTouched)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, there needs to be a method of activating an event. Lets say the event is a function

```
local function activateEvent()
    -- do something
end
```

To check if variable 'x' is within the range 0 to 100, you would need to check `if x >= 0 and x <= 100`. Putting this in code would look like this

```
local function activateEvent()
    -- do something
end
local x = 40; -- replace 40 with whatever you want to check
if x >= 0 and x <= 100 then
     activateEvent();
end
```